# PDO Deleting entries from table that does not exist in post request data

Tags: mysql

I have a table which consist of columns `person_id, level_id, is_admin`

```
person_id | level_id | is_admin
--------------------------------
1         | 1        | 1
1         | 2        | 0
3         | 2        | 1
```

In the server side, I have a function that accepts a request data which is an array of objects:

```
[
    {person_id: 5, level_id: 1, is_admin: 1}, 
    {person_id: 1, level_id: 2, is_admin: 0}
]
```

What I want to achieve is that, delete rows from the table whose values of columns `person_id, level_id, is_admin` does not exists in the post request data.

For example, the expected output of the delete query:

```
person_id | level_id | is_admin
--------------------------------
1         | 1        | 1
3         | 2        | 1
```

Notice that the second row is deleted.

**EDIT:** You might wonder `delete entries that do not exists in post data`, yes that's right. because the function meant to insert things in the table and delete existing rows that does not exist in the post data.

My current delete query is:

```
$delete = "
            DELETE FROM pivotTable
            WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT * FROM (
                    SELECT
                    {$personId} AS person_id,
                    {$levelId} AS level_id,
                    {$isAdmin} AS is_admin
                ) as delTemp
            );
        ";
$this->pdo->exec($delete);
```

no error, but it seems that it's not deleting the row in the database.

Comment: You mean deleting entries that _do_ exist in the post request data. _Show SQL._

Comment: @JoopEggen I made an edit.

Comment: Please refresh, because I made another edit :)

Comment: So the "expected output" are the rows that are deleted? Good I'll drink my morning coffee. I still do not totally understand. If on test data you leave out NOT could it that be? Fortunately there are more clever SOers.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to debug this would be to run the query as a SELECT:

```
  SELECT FROM pivotTable
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT * FROM (
                    SELECT
                    {$personId} AS person_id,
                    {$levelId} AS level_id,
                    {$isAdmin} AS is_admin
                ) as delTemp
            );
```

After this you can check if the rows you want to delete are correct.

I would also recommend looking into using **WHERE NOT IN**

as in:

```
            DELETE FROM pivotTable
            WHERE (person_id, level_id, is_admin) NOT IN ((5,1,1), (1,2,0));
```

Also it seems that you aren't using prepared statements which will lead you to be vulnerable to SQL Injection, I would recommend reading on prepared statements here:
https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Comment: I tried this, but instead of strictly looking up to `person_id`, `level_id`, `is_admin` columns, what it does is it deletes all rows with `person_id` = value without considering the `level_id`, and `is_admin` columns.

Comment: Can you post the result of:

SELECt *
FROM pivotTable
            WHERE (person_id, level_id, is_admin) NOT IN ((5,1,1), (1,2,0));